# Implementing a custom CastsAttributes for a DateTimeZone in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am new to laravel, so I'd like to have some advice on how to create a good Model.

My idea is to add clear datatypes to each model property, by using the [casts functionality](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting).

I found no way on how to define a [DateTimeZone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) type yet, so I wrote a [custom cast](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts):

```php
<?php

namespace App\Casts;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\CastsAttributes;

// https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php
class DateTimeZone implements CastsAttributes
{
    /**
     * Cast the given value.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return \DateTimeZone
     */
    public function get($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
    {
        if ($value === null) {
            return null;
        }
        if ($value instanceof \DateTimeZone) {
            return $value;
        }
        if (is_string($value)) {
            return new \DateTimeZone($value);
        }
        throw new Exception('Unknown type when getting DateTimeZone');
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the given value for storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  array  $value
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return string|\DateTimeZone
     */
    public function set($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
    {
        if ($value === null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (is_string($value)) {
            return new \DateTimeZone($value);
        }
        if ($value instanceof \DateTimeZone) {
            return $value->getName();
        }
        throw new Exception('Unknown type when setting DateTimeZone');
    }
}
```

This works so far, however I've added getters and setters for `string` AND `DateTimeZone` on each. This was the only way to convert the json `string` to `DateTimeZone` and back to `string` for the database. However I am not sure if I implemented this as intended. Can someone please give me a feedback on that?

Comment: Don't see any issue with your implementation. However would like to make a suggestion - you can use PHP `match` to cleanup your code and get rid of multiple `if` conditions in the methods. https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php

Comment: I was confused, I'd expect to have 4 instead of 2 functions for converting. 2 for the database direction, 2 for the json direction. Thanks for the match hint!

Comment: The set method should only return a string or null. It has to be a primitive that can exist in the database. The get method should equally only return a DateTimeZone or a null value.

Comment: It would also be a good to provide an example of a model using this cast and how you're setting and getting the attribute.

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected that now to only convert string <--> DateTimeZone. I thought it makes sense to use the DateTimeZone object in the model, as it feels more native. From json I only get a string as input. I've also asked how to convert the json to the model here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72377838/14348748

Answer (score 0):

So here is the correct cast, that could be used.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Casts;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\CastsAttributes;

// https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php
class DateTimeZone implements CastsAttributes
{
    /**
     * Cast the given value.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return ?\DateTimeZone
     */
    public function get($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
    {
        if ($value === null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (! is_string($value)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('The given value is not a string instance.');
        }

        return new \DateTimeZone($value);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the given value for storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  array  $value
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return ?string
     */
    public function set($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
    {
        if ($value === null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (! $value instanceof \DateTimeZone) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('The given value is not an DateTimeZone instance.');
        }

        return $value->getName();
    }

    /**
     * Get the serialized representation of the value.
     * https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#array-json-serialization
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function serialize($model, string $key, $value, array $attributes)
    {
        return $value->getName();
    }
}
```

However I do not use this anymore, as it is simpler to just validate the timezone using a validator and simply go with the string, instead of the native DateTimeZone object.