# Convert json request to eloquent model and back to database

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am new to laravel and what I currently do not understand is, how to properly do the conversion between `json` <--> `model` <--> `database`.

Let's assume all three variants are differently represented. I will take a quite uncommon example, just to understand it better.

So what if the requirement is to:

- Json data must be lower case `test example`
- Model should be upper case for each first letter (ucwords) `Test Example`
- Database should store as upper case `TEST EXAMPLE`

I know that there are [`CastsAttributes`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts) which to me sound like the usecase is to convert between `model` <--> `database`.

Also there is the [`serialize()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#array-json-serialization) function, that can be used to convert back the json from the model: `json` <-- `model`.

What I am missing is the `json` --> `model` conversion. How can we do that? What is the best practice here? I've also seen the [`Resource`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources) class, but I found no native way to convert this to a model.

What would be the best practice?

Comment: Opinion based question are off-topic in SO. please read [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: IMHO the problem starts with the requirement, that is a really BAD practice in itself. Data should be presentation agnostic, that is, the presentation issues must be solved outside the model. The casing of a given field is a good example, it must be solved in views, not models.

Answer (score 0):

not really sure to understand what you're trying to do but you shouldn't be really about it..

if you send json to the server you just have to do the mapping with your model  ... let's say you sent

```
{name: John, lastname: Doe}.
```

In your controller you juste access the request and do the mapping with your model with something like

```
myModel = new Model();
myModel->name = $request->name;
...
myModel->save();
```

And then for the format, in your model you can put a method like

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

...
public function name():Attribute
{
     return new Attribute(
          function($value) { return Str::ucfirst($value);},
          function($value) { return Str::upper($value); }
     );
}
```

The **Attribute** class take 2 closures as params : one for the *get Method* and one for the *set Method*) so the model will automatically know how it's supposed to format the value when you set / get it

Comment: So the `json` --> `model` mapping has to be done in the controller class?

Comment: yes you can do it there